# Modifica onBackPressed() para salir al pulsar dos veces

Tags: android

estoy creando mi app, estoy empezando y solo de momento se hacer el menú para salir de la app  pulsando dos veces.

Me gustaría si podéis ayudarme para cuando pulse el botón atrás del menú que viene con android vaya para atrás y no salga al pulsar dos veces.

Este es el codigo que tengo actualmente:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Pulsa dos veces para salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de usar una variable de tipo `boolean` que es `doubleBackToExitPressedOnce`, Te sugiero crear una variable que cuente las veces que diste clic, y solo permita salir cuando se dio clic en 2 ocasiones y estas no sucedieron en un intervalo de 2 segundos:

```
private int counterExit = 0;

...
...

public void onBackPressed() {

 if (counterExit > 1) {
        //Reinicia valor de variable counterExit.
        counterExit = 0;
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
}

//Aumenta valor de variable con cada clic.
counterExit++;

//this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Pulsa dos veces para salir", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;
       //Reinicia valor de variable que determina salir si transcurrieron 2 segundos.
       counterExit =0;
    }
  }, 2000);

}
```

Comment: He probado lo que me has indicando, pero lo que quiero es cuando estoy en la página de inicio y navego por el menu de la app, cuando le de para atrás no me diga que pulse dos veces para salir, lo quiero que haga es retroceder por los menus que he navegado hacia atrás, he probado tu código y no funciona, te lo agradezco mucho, voy a seguir intentandolo o si se te ocurre algo mas te lo agradeceria! =)